# How can I rename my root OneDrive folder?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, microsoft

Here's what happened:

I had a OneDrive Business acoount at my Windows 10, the path was "D:\OneDrive - Company", as usual. I had to re-link the account due to an error with another account, but my company manager has changed the Company Name (and I don't have access to change it), so now the path is: "D:\OneDrive - NewName".

The thing is: if I set this folder, I'll have a doubled folder with almost the same content as the previous one. I can't change the previous one, even though I have unlinked it. I can't set the OneDrive account to use the same folder because the Company name has changed.

What do I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you ask your Company for help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. I'll try to clarify what I wanted:

First, I had a OneDrive folder being synced, named "OneDrive - Company". I had to reinstall OneDrive, but when I reinstalled, I discovered the Company name was changed at Office, and I don't have permission to edit it. So when I reinstalled, I had a new folder named "OneDrive - NewCompany", and the previous folder named "OneDrive - Company" was there, useless. I couldn't delete nor rename it. My question was: How could I rename the previous folder from "OneDrive - Company" to "OneDrive - NewCompany", so the OneDrive would sync into it again, instead of creating a new folder.

Here's what I did though:

I logged in with OneDrive and let it create the new folder, then I closed the app and went into %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business1, found the *.ini file who had the path location and changed the new folder as the previous one. When I reopened OneDrive, it prompted an error: "This isn't your OneDrive folder", and there was two options: "Try again" and "change folder". I hit "try again" and it started syncing it normally.